# Change Column align footnotes in word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, microsoft-office-2013, footnote

As you know Microsoft added multi column footnote in word 2013.
But I can't change direction of column in footnote. I use Persian language in my document, and I want that the first column of footnote appears at the right of page.
Is it possible?